# Firebase equalto is returning null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to check if a value named 'status' is equal to 'verkoper'.
But in this case it stills returns null, or what i wrote in my code "it does not works , even when it says 'verkoper' in the database.

Picture of the database structure

[image]

While the database rules are set like this

[image]

In my sign up, I push the name of the ref key equal as the uid like this, so I can easily check every user:

```
const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref().child('accounts').child(uid).set({
```

So after that done, I try to check if the currentuser's status is equal to "verkoper"

```
let user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  console.log(user_id);
  const ref = firebase.database().ref(`accounts/${user_id}`);
  ref.orderByChild('status').equalTo('verkoper').once('value').then((userSnapshot) => {
    if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
      //allow user perform action
      console.log('it works');
    }else {
      console.log('it does not work');
      // do not allow
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I hope this was enough information to figure out what the problem might be

Comment: It might be an artifact from the screenshot, but in your picture of the database structure it looks like the values only have one quotation mark each. Is it possible the database is treating the strings as `"verkoper` and `"test@ts.test`?

Comment: i first thought that was the issue but the box where you see "verkoper is just to small, if I click in it and I go to the right, it shows me the other "